# How to know what causes nginx to stop?

Tags: linux, nginx, service

My Website was down because nginx service stopped. `sudo service nginx restart` was enough to bring it back.

To make sure this will not happen again, I want to know what causess nginx daemon to stop.

Are their any dedicated logs I can check to make such a diagnosis ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the system log (`/var/log/messages` on RH-based systems and `/var/log/syslog` on Debian-based systems). You can also check the nginx error log for anything relevant. If it doesn't capture what you're after you may try to increase the log level via the `error_log` directive and wait for it to happen again. For example:

```
error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log debug;
```

Note that `debug` level will produce *a lot* of output. So be prepared for that. [More information on the `error_log` directive here.](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log)

Answer (score 2):

You can check the error logs in this directory:

```
/var/log/nginx/
```

Example:

```
sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Comment: does it even mention when the daemon stops and starts ?

Comment: Yes sir. It does.